# Advanced Filter Un-collapses all rows which are grouped

Tags: vbscript

I have a worksheet which has rows of 5 (or more) related items. I used the Data Group command to collapse the 5 related row such that only the first (title row) is visible. There are lots of 5 row entries. When performing an advanced filter, the result of the filter "un-collapses" all of the rows. Is there an any macro or vb script which could be implemented to re-collapse all grouped rows after the Advanced Filter has done its work?

Thanks in advance for any help you may offer.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried so far?

Comment: how can I add the file? I grouped accessories of the main component beneath it. when I filtered the different components by manufacturer the group is expanding as the accessories row also has the manufacturer in it. But I need the filtering operation to be perform only for the main components.All I need is when I perform the filtering operation the grouped rows shouldn't be collapsed / expand.

Comment: Can anyone kindly help me with this, I am in emergency to submit it.